# Suppress validation attributes for Razor Pages property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

`MyPage.cshtml.cs`

```cs
[ValidateNever]                            // <-----
public string ProductName { get; set; }
```

`MyPage.cshtml`

```html
<input asp-for=@Model.ProductName />
```

That renders:

```html
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ProductName field is required." id="ProductName" name="ProductName" value="">
```

I expected `[ValidateNever]` would suppress validation attributes, but they are emitted anyway.

How can I suppress them?

Comment: @Jackdaw That's a pretty good idea. Unfortunately I get the same weird result. Maybe it's some errant config option somewhere. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Jackdaw Same result. Weird. I'll try start from a fresh project template and see what happens. It's probably a Heisenbug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From .NET 6+ the non-nullable property must be required, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

**The easist way, change your code like below:**

```
[ValidateNever]                            // <-----
public string? ProductName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to nullable was the solution. I even removed `[ValidateNever]`.